# db.getCollectionNames() equivalent in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

mongodb `db.getCollectionNames()`command will give you all collection names what are all there in the current db, in a list.

I want the same output using pymongo. I googled some time and couldn't find anything like  that.

Is anything like that exists ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 collection_names()
```

Will show you the collections of the current database.

From documentation:

### `collection_names()`

> Get a list of all the collection names in this database.
>   [[**read more**]](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.collection_names)

Comment: Thanks @John. Its working fine. Please tell me how did you get the answer. When googled it I couldn't find it.

Comment: Yes :-). I got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since pymongo 3.7, `collection_names()` is deprecated and the correct way to get collection names is **`list_collection_names()`**